# Jquery+React $.each() not rebinding my callback to the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm not sure if React is explicitly relevant, other than that it requires me to explicitly bind the function which is calling `.each()`.

But I have a `submit()` function for a dynamically generated form. I am using `.each()` to iterate through the various fields to get the data. As I understand, the callback I supply to `.each()` is supposed to become bound to the DOM element for the current iteration. Instead however, `this` is referring to the class that the `submit()` function is bound to. It looks roughly like:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    submit() {
        $('input.my-input').each(() => {
            console.log(this);
        });
    }
}
```

And my class object is being printed to the devtools console instead of the DOM element, ie.:

```
> MyClass {props:..., refs:..., state:...}
```

I'm assuming this is somehow an issue with `submit()` being bound. How can I otherwise work around this?

Comment: Why are you using DOM events in react? You should not really be manipulating the DOM in react, that is what react is for.

Comment: Arrow functions have no explicit `this`. try `$('input.my-input').each(function() {console.log(this); });`

Comment: @epascarello Its a pretty situational popup form, only consisting of checkboxes/radios and the jQuery stuff is all read-only. jQuery just made for a lighter and more readable way to do what I wanted instead of dealing with the overhead of react state.